# DUMP in pig taking long time

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

I have a pig script where we do some data manipulation with the help UDF.

Let us understand an Example.

```
data=someoperation;
olddata = newoperation;
Uniondata = UNION data,olddata;
DUMP Uniondata;
```

So, here i use DUMP to make sure that all the above statements are executed and not for streaming the data to console. I think the way of execution of DUMP causing problems related to performance. Here, to make sure that data and olddata return nothing form UDF. How can i make sure these statements executes without using DUMP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ILLUSTRATE operator for that purpose.

> Use the ILLUSTRATE operator to review how data is transformed through
>   a sequence of Pig Latin statements. ILLUSTRATE allows you to test your
>   programs on small datasets and get faster turnaround times.

So simply replace DUMP with ILLUSTRATE. Also sample the dataset for testing purposes.

```
data=someoperation;
data= SAMPLE data 0.01; --# sample by 1%
olddata = newoperation;
uniondata = UNION data,olddata;
ILLUSTRATE Uniondata;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [LIMIT](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/cookbook.html#Use+the+LIMIT+Operator) to reduce the size of your data.

```
A = operation1;
B = operation2;
A1 = LIMIT A 100;
B1 = LIMIT B 100; 
A1B1 = UNION A1,B1;
DUMP A1B1;
```